# Trouble processing parameters when creating a new email in IBM Notes from powershell?

Tags: powershell, lotus-notes

I have a parameter that I pass to IBM notes to generate a new email that is passed to `notes.exe` as follows:

```
 mailto:bob@yahoo.com?subject=For Employee Someguy Somsirname?body= Hi, Someguy%0AI am emailing you in regard to Someguy.  Unable his\her Stuff. Please contact his\her.%0A%0A           %0AThank you,%0A            %0A
```

I'd like to be able to call this from Powershell, but when it calls `notes.exe` Notes says `There was an error processing command line arguments`

If I just copy and paste the parameter above and put it in double quotes it works just fine from powershell, but if I pass it as a variable it results in the aforementioned error.

Is there any thing here that when stored as a string would cause an issue passing it as a parameter?  Characters that might need searched/replaced/escaped?

Comment: How are you invoking the executable?

Comment: `& $executableName $optionsParameters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to trim the parameter string.

In the variable that contained the parameters, I needed to call it's `.Trim()` function to clip off the space at the start and end of the string.  After I did that it worked.

It takes this:

```
" mailto:bob@yahoo.com?subject=For Employee Someguy Somsirname?body= Hi, Someguy%0AI am emailing you in regard to Someguy.  Unable his\her Stuff. Please contact his\her.%0A%0A           %0AThank you,%0A            %0A"
```

and makes it this:

```
"mailto:bob@yahoo.com?subject=For Employee Someguy Somsirname?body= Hi, Someguy%0AI am emailing you in regard to Someguy.  Unable his\her Stuff. Please contact his\her.%0A%0A           %0AThank you,%0A            %0A"
```

Comment: In order for your answer to be useful to future readers, can you please explain the solution in more detail?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to make the answer more articulate last night.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to others if you showed the actual powershell script in the question, and then the corrected script in the answer.